# fft visualization using fftw and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, fftw

Im using the following code to generate the visualization of fourier transform using FFTW and OpenCV. However, I'm only getting the upper part of the image correctly.
Can anyone explain if there is something wrong with the code?

fft stores the fftw_execute data.

```
int nl= fftvis->height; // number of lines
// total number of element per line
int nc= fftvis->width * fftvis->nChannels;

// get the pointer to the image buffer
unsigned char *data= reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>
(fftvis->imageData);
k =0;
for (int x=1; x<nl; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<nc; y+= fftvis->nChannels) {
        data[y] = 10*log(sqrt((pow(fft[k++][0],2) + pow(fft[k++][1],2))));
        //k+=1;
    } // end of line

    data+= step;
    // next line
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling fftw? Which fftw functions are you using?

Comment: just before the chunk of code im calling fftw_execute and data is stored in "fft". I'm trying to visualize the magnitude of the fourier transform.

Comment: Which fftw plan are you using? Do you have your data sizes aligned correctly? Are you doing fftw on doubles and then displaying floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill each channel's RGB, but you are stepping over channel data when `y+= fftvis->nChannels` is executed.
Also, `data+= step;` would skip `step` bytes of your data, this is not necessary if you align the processing properly.